# Найдите сумму всех четырехзначных чисел, сумма цифр каждого из которых равна 20

Tags: python

не могу решить, вот мой код в чем ошибка?

```
s = 0
for i in(1000,10000):
  while i > 0:
    a = i%10
    s += a 
    i //= 10
    if s == 20:
      print(i)
    s = 0
```

Comment: for i in(1000,10000): тут же цикл по tuple(1000,10000) . range не забыли?). Но в прочем это не единственная проблема)

Answer (score 2):

Вроде вот так

```
result = 0

for number in range(1000, 10000):
    if sum(map(int, str(number))) == 20:
        result += number

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

в одну строчку

```
print(sum(i for i in range(1000, 10000) if sum(map(int, str(i))) == 20))
```

ну или можете сделать так

```
def sum_of_digits(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        sum += num % 10
        num //= 10
    return sum

sum_number = 0
    
for number in range(1000, 10000):
    if(sum_of_digits(number)==20):
        sum_number += number

print(sum_number)
```

еще 1 вариант в 1 строку с использованием `filter`

```
print(sum(filter(lambda number: sum(map(int,str(number)))==20, range(1000, 10000))))
```

Comment: list можно убрать

Comment: @TigerTV.ru даБ точно

Comment: `range(1199, 9921, 9)` - в 9 раз быстрее

Comment: Квадратные скобки тоже можно не писать )